# dynamically change method name inside array in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a user object which i access like this.. `user.email, user.first_name`

Now I want to loop through each and return a message based on the current key in loop somewhat like this.

```
[user.first_name, user.email, user.last_name].each do |key|
      puts "#{key} is required"
 end
```

The above works but loops through `values` instead of `fields`. so will do this below but how to prepend user to keys and get values inside array?

```
[first_name, email, last_name].each do |key|
 #inside here I want to prepend the user to the keys so that I can access like user.key 

 puts "#{user.key} is required" 
end
```

If this was a string we can concatenate but how to deal with this here as its a method call?

Comment: Are you asking how to use `key` as a method call on `user`?

Comment: @jvillian yes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ActiveRecord you can access properties via the `[]` method:

```
[ :first_name, :email, :last_name ].each do |key|
  unless (user[key])
    puts "#{key} is required"
  end
end
```

This generally a lot safer than the `send` approach because it's not calling arbitrary methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```
user.send(key)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
[first_name, email, last_name].each do |key|
 puts user.send(key)
end
```